# Func<T, TResult> for with void TResult?

Tags: c#, .net

`Func<>` is very convenient in .NET. Is there a way i can specify the param type and have the result value as void? I'd like to pass `void Write(string)` as a parameter.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) - "Encapsulates a method that takes a single parameter and does not return a value"

Answer (score 14):

I believe you're looking for the `Action<T>` family of delegate types.

Answer (score -2):

It's not perfect, but sometimes when I want to fake this behavior against an existing function (and I'd rather not re-implement it as `Action<TResult>`) I'll just return `null` and throw the value away.

```
Func<T, TResult> myFunc = (inVar) =>
{
    // do work...

    return null as object;
};
```